# CoreData duplicate results, timestamp predicate

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a database with steps and timestamps. Each record may for example 50 steps and a timestamp. I am trying to filter through these records with NSPredicate to filter by the hour to display a bar graph and then display a "total" for the day.

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Activity"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(timestamp >= %@) AND (timestamp <= %@)", from, to];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[descriptor];

NSArray *activities = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

**From** date and **To** dates are provided as follows:

```
2015-03-07 05:00:00 +0000 - 2015-03-07 05:59:59 +0000
```

Which results in records:

```
Timestamp: 2015-03-07 05:59:53 +0000, Steps: 0   2015-03-07 05:00:00 +0000 - 2015-03-07 05:59:59 +0000
```

Problem is, with the more **steps** entries that are added, the "total" count seems to increase, doubling, tripling, etc as the entries grow. It appears that the predicate may be double counting certain records depending on their timestamp.

### Getting Steps from Phone

```
- (void)getSteps
{
    __block NSInteger _numberOfSteps = 0;
    __block NSInteger _numberOfRest = 0;
    __block NSInteger _numberOfLow = 0;
    __block NSInteger _numberOfHigh = 0;

    __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
    [_activityManager queryActivityStartingFromDate:startDate toDate:endDate toQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(NSArray *activities, NSError *error)
     {
         for (NSInteger i = 0; i < activities.count; i++)
         {
             CMMotionActivity *activity = activities[i];

             NSTimeInterval duration = 0.0;
             if (i < activities.count-1)
             {
                 CMMotionActivity *nextActivity = (CMMotionActivity *)activities[i+1];
                 duration = [nextActivity.startDate timeIntervalSinceDate:activity.startDate];
             }
             else
                 duration = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:activity.startDate];


             if (activity.walking)
                 _numberOfLow += round(duration);
             else if (activity.running)
                 _numberOfHigh += round(duration);
             else
                 _numberOfRest += round(duration);
         }

         if (activities.count == 0)
             _numberOfRest = (NSInteger)[weakSelf reportingInterval];

         if ( [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate] > [self reportingInterval] )
             _numberOfRest = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];


         [_stepCounter queryStepCountStartingFrom:startDate to:endDate toQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(NSInteger numberOfSteps, NSError *error)
          {
              _numberOfSteps = numberOfSteps;

              // Nothing special, no calculations here, just creates record
              [self addSteps:@{@"timestamp":[ActivityEngine dateSpan:CDPDateSpanLocalTime],
                               @"steps":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_numberOfSteps],
                               @"rest":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_numberOfRest],
                               @"low":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_numberOfLow],
                               @"high":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_numberOfHigh]
                               }];
          }];
     }];
}
```

### How can I ensure that no record is counted twice?

Comment: You might add duplicate entries when creating the entries. Show the code 1) where you create the records, 2) how you calculate the total.

Comment: @Mundi added getSteps example

Answer (score 1):

In your code you iterate through all activities and query a certain date range. If you do this repeatedly, surely your step count will double and triple, etc.

Make sure you update your data incrementally. The reason for the error is how and how often you call the `getSteps` function. Perhaps you should keep track of the date ranges you have already stored and exclude those ranges from the next query.